# comparing pointer to base type with derived type's pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

Say there is a base class B and derived classes D1, D2, D3.

```
B* b;
D1 d1;
D2 d2;
D2 *pd2 = &d2;
D3 d3;
//more code placing valid data on variables
```

It is possible to say `b = &d1` or `b = pd2` somewhere in the code.
Now is it possible to compare b with pointers to d1, d2 and d3 for equality of pointers without dynamic casting? That is, can I do this:

```
if (b == &d1)
{
//do something
}
```

?

Comment: `b = pd2` is not possible, probably you means `b = &pd2`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan pd2 is a pointer, in case you missed it.

Comment: @Akilan you should have called it `pb` instead of `b`..

Comment: @Adam Yes; didn't realise before your comment. Can't change now as it would confuse answers & comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now is it possible to compare b with pointers to d1, d2 and d3 for equality of pointers without dynamic casting?

Yes.

`if (b == pd2)` is perfectly fine to see if `b` and `pd2` point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

`if (b == &d1)` will simply compare the pointer addresses unless an operator overload has been created that does a compare based on the information stored within the object.

As a side note, you cannot do `b = pd2` based on your code, unless your overload the operator correctly within one or both objects, or instead use `b = &pd2`

Comment: Yes it is *not* a deep comparison.

Comment: I don't want to compare information stored in two objects. I want to compare if two pointers point to same object. Only that one of the pointers is of type of the base class.

Comment: You can't define overloaded operators on built-in types, so the second half of the first sentence does not apply. `if (b == &d1)` simply compares the values of the two pointers. Always.

Comment: @bizzehdee Nevermind that it's not what OP wanted, but "unless an operator overload has been created" is impossible. You can't overload pointer operators. One of the two operands must be a class or enum.